# Untarring single file from large tarball

Tags: ruby, file, tar, zlib

I have a very large tarball that has around 500 files inside of it.

I'm writing a program to extract a single file from this tarball using `package` and `zlib`.. My question being, how do I extract a single file from inside this tarball, the tar has a directory inside of it also called `home/common/4000_ss` can I extract this single file without taking the directory with the file?

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems/package'
require 'fileutils'
require 'zlib'

class ArchiveManager

  attr_accessor :folio_num

  def initialize(folio_num)
    @folio_num = folio_num
  end

  def num_check
    if folio_num =~ /^\d{4,7}$/ #<= Thank you Tin Man.
      search_for_spreadsheet
    else
      puts <<-EOF

        USAGE: unarchive_ss <folio number>

      EOF
    end
  end

  def search_for_spreadsheet
    location = FileUtils.chdir("/home/<dir>/<user>/archive")
    digits = `grep -lr #{folio_num}.ods *.txt`
    file_name = digits.match(/\d+/).to_s
    puts "Spreadsheet found in UW_archive_#{file_name}.tgz"
    extract(file_name, location)
  end

  def extract(file_name, location)
    extract_tar = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open("/home/<dir>/<user>/archive/UW_archive_#{file_name}.tgz"))
    extract_tar.rewind
    extract_tar.each do |tar|
      puts tar.full_name
      puts tar.directory?
      puts tar.file?
    end
  end
end


#/2715015
test = ArchiveManager.new(ARGV[0])
test.num_check
```

Example of usage right now:

> ```
> []$ ruby unarchive_ss 2715015 #I know I'm asking it to do all of this.
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2719102.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2718427.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2721372.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2718986.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2718893.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2719048.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2719572.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/10853.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2719161.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2719764.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2718473.ods
> false
> true
> home/common/4000_UW_spreadsheets/2718712.ods
> false
> true
> ```

Comment: Have you tried putting the entire path along with the name of the file on where you call `zlib`?

Comment: @Ekult3k Yes I just tried, and it comes up as this: `/home/<dir>/<user>/archive/UW_archive_20120625.tgz/home/common/4000_ss/2715015.ods (Errno::ENOTDIR)`

Comment: The reason it's outputting that is because that's what you're telling it to do, I'm not sure if Ruby can actually untar a file and put it into a directory, you may have to use a bash command here.. I could be wrong, I k ow that Ruby can read from tarballs, and write to them, but pulling a file out of the tarball I'm not sure about..